# "Unknown Provider" AngularJS ngRoute

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm working for the first time with Angular.js. I already search too many articles in order to correct this error. I receive the following error when my Index.html is loaded:

[image: Error]

Here is the code:

**report-module.js**

```
    angular.module('reportTemplateApp', [
    'reportTemplateApp.services',
    'reportTemplateApp.controllers',
    'ngRoute'
]).
    config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
          .when('/slide1/:auditId', {
              templateUrl: 'slide1.html',
              controller: 'MainSlideController',
              controllerAs: 'main'
          })
          .when('/slide3/:auditId/sl/:slideId', {
              templateUrl: 'slide3.html',
              controller: 'CommonSlidesController',
              controllerAs: 'commons'
          });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);
```

**report-controller.js**

```js
angular.module('reportTemplateApp.controllers', []).
      controller('CommonSlidesController', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $routeParams, auditAPIservice) {
          $scope.id = $routeParams;
          $scope.slideId;
          $scope.slide = [];

          //CANCEL EDIT
          $scope.cancelSave = function () {
              $scope.mainList = $scope.backupList;
          }

          //SAVE DATA
          $scope.saveSlide = function () {
              try {

                  auditAPIservice.ItemsData($scope.mainList).then(function (response) {
                      if (response.message = "Success") {
                      }
                      else {
                          $scope.mainList = $scope.backupList;
                      }
                  });
              } catch (ex) {
                  $scope.showToast('UPS! Something happen ' + ex.message);
              }
          }


          //GET DATA
          reportAPIservice.getSlide(2, 3).then(function (response) {
              if (response.message = "Success") {
                  $scope.mainList = response.data.ReportSlideInfo
                  angular.copy($scope.mainList, $scope.backupList);
              }
              else {

                  //SOME ERROR SHOWING HERE
              }

          });

          $scope.showToast = function (message) {
              angular.element(document).ready(function () {
                  toast(message, 4000);
              });
          }
      }).
```

**Index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

     <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/materialize/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Content/materialize/materialize.css" />
</head>
<body ng-app="reportTemplateApp">

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
            $('.collapsible').collapsible();
        });
    </script>

 
     <a href="Slide3/2/2">Text Link</a><br/>


    <div ng-view></div>


    <script src="../Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-resource.js"></script>

    <script src="../Scripts/SPS/Report/report-module.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/SPS/Report/report-controller.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/SPS/Report/report-service.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know what it's wrong. Another thing, the error shows when I add  in the Index page, if I remove it no error is present.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this. I had (I don't know why) in the project mixed versions of the angular.js(1.2.23) and angular-route.js (1.3.8). After change one with the same version of the other there is no error and routing works.